# Share FME workflows with other organizations

Tags: fme-form

Can we publish FME Workbenches to GitHub, to enable sharing these with other organizations.A custom transformer might be a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can publish to [fme store.](https://store.safe.com/)
This would allow other fme users to directly access the workbench.
Safe also has their own [github](https://github.com/safesoftware).
So the short answer is yes. But using your own other users would not have a way to discover you as easily as if you use the Safe methods.

Comment: FME Store is a good option, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: do you know how to mark as an answer?